# ¿Tiene la palabra "cafetero" más significados de los que incluye el diccionario?

Tags: expresiones, significado, españa, neologismos

¿Tiene "cafetero" (o la expresión "para los muy *cafeteros*") alguna acepción distinta a las que refleja el diccionario?

En el diccionario del DRAE [todas las acepciones de cafetero](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6bdGFJA) están directamente relacionadas con el café

[image]

Sin embargo a veces oigo expresiones como "esto es para los muy *cafeteros*" o "esta persona es muy *cafetera*" con el sentido (yo entiendo) de "esto es para la gente a la que le guste mucho el tema". Por ejemplo

> Puedo recomendaros unos libros sobre este tema, pero son para los muy cafeteros
>
> Ese tertuliano es muy cafetero
>
> Ese tema es par los muy cafeteros

¿Puede alguien aclarar otras acepciones del adjetivo `cafetero` aparte de las indicadas por el diccionario (o explicar cómo las del diccionario se aplican a expresiones como "esto es para los muy cafeteros/esta persona es muy cafetera")?

---

**EDIT**
Expando con algunos ejemplos encontrados con unas búsquedas simples de google.

Añado que la expresión aparece no solo como "eso es para los muy cafeteros" sino también como "eso es café para los muy cafeteros". Quizá sea algo como estos es "muy bueno" (Como si dijese "esto es café del bueno"\ para los  que nos muy cafeteros", o en general, esto es X para aquellos a los que les gusta mucho X)

1. [Es MAD MEN, CAFÉ para MUY CAFETEROS??](https://www.forocoches.com/foro/showthread.php?t=5842344)
2. [eso es cafe para muy cafeteros](https://twitter.com/elmonaguillo/status/382855235905282048?lang=en)
3. [Takashi Inui, para béticos 'muy cafeteros'](https://www.lavanguardia.com/deportes/20180619/45270310154/takashi-inui-para-beticos-muy-cafeteros.html)

Comment: @ukemi actualizo con el tag "España". Las oigo mucho en You Tube (porque ya no vivo ahí y no las oigo "a pie de calle") en canales de noticias y política cuando se refieren a algún tertuliano, escritor o pensador o a algún tipo de obra. Como si quisieran decir por ejemplo que un libro es muy denso y muy difícil de entender (muy coñazo) y que solo estaría recomendado para aquellos "con aguante". Eso es lo que intuyo. No estoy seguro, de ahí la pregunta a ver si alguien me confirma.

Comment: Curioso... Nunca lo había oido hasta hoy y he buscado también si "cafetero" tendría algún otro significado del que parecía tenere en el contexto que era como "aficionado" o "experto. Y aquí lo he confirmado.
Imagino que si este uso se sigue expandiendo al final la Academia también acabará aceptándolo.

Comment: En el ajedrez se usa esta palabra con un significado distinto; por eso no escribo esto como respuesta, pero sí da para comentario. Un jugador *cafetero* es el que tiene un estilo más dado a los golpes tácticos que a la profundidad estratégica. El término viene de que muchos aficionados a jugar en lugares públicos, como cafés, contra jugadores que puedan aparecer por allí son dados a intentar usar celadas y trucos tácticos variados para sorprender a su oponente.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No es extraño que el diccionario no pueda/quiera recoger cada figura retórica que se hace popular, a menos que su uso este muy asentado y parezca que no dejará de ser popular. Y esta en concreto creo que tiene un origen relativamente reciente: una parodia de un lema publicitario que es muy útil como símil fácil de entender (esencial para que tenga cierto efecto humorístico) y en mi opinión es entendible que no esté aún en el diccionario, pues podría dejar de ser popular cuando ya nadie se acuerde del lema publicitario que lo originó.

El lema decía **«[Marca comercial], el café de los muy cafeteros»**. El anuncio mostraba mientros al apuesto y elegante experto de la empresa (bien trajeado o en plan Indiana Jones), seleccionando el mejor grano en el lugar de producción, y finalmente con una taza de café en la mano, te miraba a fijamente y decía «Mi café» con voz de Terminator (su vídeo se puede encontrar fácilmente en Internet, pero no veo adecuado enlazarlo ni citar la marca).

La expresión se hizo famosa, cómo no, por la insistente publicidad durante años. El anuncio asociaba al «muy cafetero», no a alguien «muy aficionado» al café, como dice el diccionario, sino a una mezcla de *barista* y *yuppie*, un exclusivo tipo de hombre de negocios exigente, que sabe distinguir y apreciar el sabor del café de calidad superior, solo apto para paladares entrenados.... *ergo* si compras esa marca de café (aquí venía  la falacia subliminal de turno) es porque eres de ese selecto grupo de **iniciados, expertos, entendidos**...

El mensaje oculto lo recordaba mejor que el lema, que no era «Solo para los muy cafeteros» como puse inicialmente En cualquier caso, la connotación elitista del mensaje era evidente. Por eso, creo que siempre que la he escuchado (en sentido figurado) podría considerarla un sinónimo de «entendido», y lógicamente también de «aficionado», ya que va implícito (raramente alguien se especializa en un tema que no le interesa) aunque, según el contexto y entonación, quizás alguna vez eso pueda tener una connotación negativa (de la afición a la **adicción** solo hay un paso...).

Comment: O sea, cafetero es desde entonces un entendido o aficionada por lo general....?

Comment: @Lambie Por lo general, pero siempre habrá que considerar el contexto, que a peor mejor se refiere a que gusta mucho el café y punto, sin sentido figurado alguno. `:-)`

Comment: Corregido el lema publicitario, que lo recordaba mal, pero en sentido de la respuesta no cambia.

Comment: @Leonardo Mis disculpas: *barista* es un término italiano que se ha hecho universal (se usa tal cual en francés, alemán, portugués, inglés, etc. y hasta existe una *World Barista Championship*). El barista es una especie de barman de la cafetería, que además de saber hacer cócteles con café, es un experto en la calidad del café, tueste, elaboración y presentación del café, de modo que no te sirve una taza de café, sino una «obra de arte»,  alguien literalmente «muy cafetero».  Lo puedes encontrar en Wikipedia y muchas otras páginas en castellano.

Comment: @Lambie - Se puede decir "Soy muy juguero" (me encanta tomar el jugo), "Mi hermano es súper telefonero" (a mi hermano le encanta usar el teléfono a cada rato), etc.

Comment: @aparente001 Según mi esposo, cafetero sí, juguero,no. O sea a pesar de ser muy juguetón con su proprio idioma (es poeta y gran amador de Cervantes) no piensa que (u)ero se pueda añadir a cualquier palabra a no ser en plan broma. Pero te agradesco la "ponencia". :)

Comment: @Lambie - Ahí tenemos material para una pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Desde mi lugar puedo responder que, al menos en muchos lugares de Latinoamerica, se utiliza el termino `"cafeteros"` refiriéndose a los ciudadanos colombianos, ya que su país es un gran productor de café y en el ámbito del fútbol es muy común llamarles así internacionalmente:

> #### [cafetero, -a.](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=cafetero)
>
> **I.   1.**    adj. *ES, Pe, Ch, Py.* *En el periodismo deportivo,* relativo a Colombia.

Comment: Interesante, pero no parece coincidir con el uso que veo yo. No creo que quieran decir "esto es para los muy colombianos" sino "esto es para aquellos con muchas ganas, aguante o interés por el tema".